Error code CS1061, and SerializeField not showing in the Unity Editor / C#
I'm having some problems with my code, and I'm not sure how to solve it, as I'm still new to programming. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AttackingMechanic : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Transform attackTransform; // These just refuse to show up in the editor for whatever reason.
    [SerializeField] private float attackRange = 1.5f;
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask attackableLayer;
    [SerializeField] private float damageAmount = 1f;

    private RaycastHit2D[] hits;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (UserInput.instance.Controls.Attack.Attack.WasPressedThisFrame()) // error CS1061
        {
            // attack
        }
    }

    private void Attack()
    {
        hits = Physics2D.CircleCastAll(attackTransform.position, attackRange, transform.right, 0f, attackableLayer);

        for (int i = 0; i < hits.Length; i++)
        {
            IDamageable iDamgageable = hits[i].collider.gameObject.GetComponent<IDamageable>();

            // if we found a Damageable
            if (iDamgageable != null)
            {
                // apply damage
                iDamgageable.Damage(damageAmount);
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
    {
        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(attackTransform.position, attackRange);
    }
}


This might be caused by another Issue I'm having with a seperate block of code that's returning error CS0120
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class UserInput : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static UserInput instance;

    [HideInInspector] public Controls controls;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            instance = this;
        }

        controls = new Controls();
    }
    private void OnEnable()
    {
        Controls.Enable(); // error CS0120
    }

    private static void OnDisable()
    {
        Controls.Disable(); // error CS0120
    }
}

It seems like it might be an Issue with the "Controls" Variable, and frankly I have no idea what I'm doing. Any help is greatly appreciated!

The type is Controls, your variable is controls (fix the case in those 2 instances of errors).

First fix all compile errors otherwise Unity doesn't know your newly added fields yet

CS0120 error means that you need an instance for a non-static member.
You created this instance on the line: controls = new Controls()
now use this instance like this:
    private void OnEnable()
    {
        controls.Enable(); // changed to lower-case controls
    }

    private static void OnDisable()
    {
        controls.Disable(); // changed to lower-case controls
    }

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0120
